# eigenvalues of matrices (with positive entries)

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-theory, singular-values

I am reading an old paper by Kawpien and Pelczynski, Studia Math. 1970. It claims that singular values of a matrix (with positive entries? I am not sure) is given by $t_i=\sqrt{\sum_{j\ge 1}a(i,j)^2}$. I am not sure why we have such a nice characterization of singular values of a matrix...

https://eudml.org/doc/217431

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is clearly a mistake, for example the singular values of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$ are $(2,0)$ and not $(\sqrt 2,\sqrt 2)$.

But it is harmless here, as the only thing that is used later in the proof is that $\sum_i t_i^2 = \sum_{i,j} |a_{i,j}|^2$, which is obvious.

Comment: I see...I thought I have missed something here...Thank you very much!